# Subversion 1.7 for OS X Lion

Tags: macos, subversion

I am quite lost, how do I get this to work. I can't find any GUI Programs that support 1.7 yet. Commandline would be okay, but I can't seem to find one!

Also how would the diff work on the commandline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Macports](http://guide.macports.org/) has a subversion port. Others are listed on the [subversion download page](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#osx) which includes [Wandisco](http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx) which seems to have a GUI.

Comment: Wandisco does not want to switch to 1.7. But I'll use your link.

Comment: They are just slow to change now do 1.6, 1.7, and 1.8 http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx